# Getting the latest features on Ubuntu Daily Builds

Tags: updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I upgraded from an alpha or beta - am I up to date if I keep upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5675/i-upgraded-from-an-alpha-or-beta-am-i-up-to-date-if-i-keep-upgrading)

If I've installed ubuntu 12.04, do I constantly have to download a new daily build to get the lates features or do the updates will automatically add them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple answer really - any ubuntu installation, whether the stable/alpha or beta will receive updates as and when the package maintainers release new updates.

Thus for 12.04, a steady stream of updates are usually made available - several megabytes a day.  You can usually just leave update-manager to receive your updates.

Personally, I leave alpha/beta updates once a week because you usually see many releases of the same package over a short period.

I also separately maintain the ISO download via zsync.  In that way, if you need to trash the release, you can reload from a very recent snapshot rather than loading the last alpha/beta and updating from there.

Hang-out on the developers forum over at ubuntuforums.org.  You usually get wind of major issues quickly - that way you can make a judgment call when to best update.

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I update an ISO with zsync?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54241/how-do-i-update-an-iso-with-zsync)

Answer (score 1):

Just do the updates. With an alpha/beta release I watch irc/forms/ask ubuntu to see if there are difficulties before (mindlessly) updating.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```