# Stability of the latest daily build iso image for the released version of Ubuntu?

Tags: updates, iso

I want install ubuntu from the daily builds  [from cdimage.ubuntu.com](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/precise/daily-live/current/precise-desktop-i386.iso).

Does it have all the updated packages after the initial 12.04 release, so that I don't need to update after installation? How is its stability as compared to the official 12.04 release?

Comment: **daily builds of 12.04, not 12.10 the current development version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daily isos of final releases are updated and stable.
I suggest to keep them daily updated with zsync.

Linked Question:

[How do I update an ISO with zsync?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54241/how-do-i-update-an-iso-with-zsync)

Answer (score 2):

It is very stable, like the official release, and it updated up to the day of download, after that, you will have to update if any updates are available.