# Unable to sync Ubuntu ISO

Tags: iso, 13.04, zsync

I'm trying to sync the Ubuntu 13.04 daily ISO according to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/54244/109543). I've used this command:

```
zsync http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/raring-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
```

It worked the first time I ran it and I was able to download the entire ISO. However, any time I run it again, it fails with this error:

```
$ zsync http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/raring-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync
#################### 100.0% 13.5 kBps DONE     

reading seed file raring-desktop-amd64.iso: ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************Read raring-desktop-amd64.iso. Target 89.4% complete.      
downloading from http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/raring-desktop-amd64.iso:
##################-- 90.1% 18.0 kBps         A   

downloading from http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/raring-desktop-amd64.iso:
##################-- 90.1%cdimages.ubuntu.com: Connection refused
##################-- 90.1% 0.0 kBps aborted    

failed to retrieve from raring-desktop-amd64.iso
Aborting, download available in raring-desktop-amd64.iso.part
```

**EDIT:** I just tried again and got this error:

```
##################-- 90.3% 54.7 kBps 24:29 ETA  bad status code 408
##################-- 90.3% 24.2 kBps aborted
```

I also tried downloading it again in a different directory, and got the same "connection refused" message twice. So it isn't just a problem with syncing already downloaded ISOs.

I've tried deleting the ISO and restarting, and also using the i386 version.

**How can I fix this so I can sync an Ubuntu 13.04 ISO using `zsync`? Or is their a better way to sync an development ISO?**

Comment: I think these images get rebuilt every time and there's no zsync support for these increments. Only for `datestamp.1` builds and releases I think this is valid. (not very sure though)

Comment: Then what are the `*.zsync` files in the `daily-live` directory for? It seems to me that although the ISOs are rebuilt each time, most of an ISO would still be the same and could be skipped downloading, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @gertvdijk is incorrect, these are built daily and iBelieve is correct in that you should only need to download the small changes each day. I've just tested and was able to download the whole iso via zsync (amd64, the link you provided), so perhaps they were having server issues.

Comment: @tgm4883 From the Q: "It worked the first time I ran it". But yes, I agree about server/connection issues are more likely.

Comment: @tgm4883 This isn't just a one-time problem. I've tried this multiple times spread over about a week, and have been able to download the ISO the first time every time I tried, but have been unable to update it fully. However (see my edit), I just tried again twice and was unable to start a new download.

Comment: @iBelieve I've just successfully updated my ISO from yesterday using zsync, so it's not some server issue. Looking at your status code, your client isn't responding to the server in a timely fashion. "The client did not produce a request within the time that the server was prepared to wait. The client MAY repeat the request without modifications at any later time."

Not sure how to fix that though :/