# What is the file size of an *buntu iso image?

Tags: files, downloads, iso

What is the file size of an *buntu iso image? I have limited internet, and I don't want to use too much of it. I want to put it on a disk or USB thumb drive and install it on a unused computer.

Answer (score 4):

These are numbers are taken directly from the iso files I've downloaded. Also if you download your iso from http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.10/ or http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ it lists the file sizes beside the names, in the directory browser at the page bottom.

**13.10:**

Ubuntu 13.10 - Desktop X86-64 = 883 MB

Ubuntu 13.10 - Desktop X86-32 = 895 MB

Ubuntu 13.10 - Server X86-64 = 672 MB

Ubuntu 13.10 - Server X86-32 = 658 MB

Lubuntu 13.10 - Desktop X86-64 = 702 MB

**12.04:**

Ubuntu 12.04 - Desktop X86-64 = 698 MB

Ubuntu 12.04 - Desktop X86-32 = 701 MB

Ubuntu 12.04.3 - Server X86-64 = 665 MB

Ubuntu 12.04.3 - Server X86-32 = 648 MB

Lubuntu 12.04 - Desktop X86-64 = 697 MB

Kubuntu 12.04.3 - Desktop X86-64 = 707 MB

Xubuntu 12.04.3 - Desktop X86-64 = 712 MB

**14.04:**

Ubuntu 14.04 - Desktop DAILYBUILD-JAN-21-2014 X86-64 = 912 MB

Answer (score 2):

According to my Downloads directory, the download size for the 64-bit 13.10 desktop ISO is 904,192 KB (883 MB).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on which image and which release you are downloading. Everything prior to 13.10 hovers around 700MB so it can fit on a standard CD. 13.10 is a bit larger around 900MB. I believe Canonical aims to keep the LTS releases under 700MB.

Comment: 4 years later… It's not. What a shame: Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS ISO image is 1.9 Gbytes. That is, it doesn't fit into a CD, and anyway it's about half the full capacity of a DVD, wasting space. There's a `mini.iso` which is really mini, less than 100 MB, of course it fits into a CD, wasting again very much space. It seems it doesn't exist an alternative (if you rule out USB). Debian offers both obvious choices in a reasonable way: a full CD (650MB) and a full DVD (4.4GB), the logical, smart choices.

Answer (score 1):

It says on the download page! Almost every browser including yourse shows how big is the file you are downloading!

Comment: Could you perhaps point out *where* it says? It would be cool if you provided instructions to tell *without* actually downloading something. Right now this is hardly an answer.

Comment: @Seth I would but it depends which file you want to download.

Comment: Try to make a good answers that covers all that nevertheless. (It doesn't have to be a huge list, take this answer for example: http://askubuntu.com/a/430045/44179)

Comment: I'm with @Seth on this one.  I'm looking right at the download page and I don't see file sizes listed anywhere: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/daily-live/pending/ always shows file size just like your browser when you start to download ANY file

Answer (score 1):

32bit: 0.713867 GB

64bit: 0.71582 GB

Information from ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 1):

All the releases of Ubuntu along with its official derivatives are linked at http://releases.ubuntu.com/. Navigate to the particular release you want to download.

Suppose you want to download the images for Precise (12.04), you would go to http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/. This page contains all the latest images available for download for 12.04 in a table showing the *names*, *last modified date*, *size* and *description* for each image. "Size" is the column which answers your question.

### Which image am I supposed to download?

`*` in the following list represents the release of Ubuntu (eg; 12.04.4 for the latest point release of Precise)

- For Desktop 32-bit: **ubuntu-*-desktop-i386.iso**
- For Desktop 64-bit: **ubuntu-*-desktop-amd64.iso**
- For Server 32-bit: **ubuntu-*-server-i386.iso**
- For Server 64-bit: **ubuntu-*-server-amd64.iso**

[image: release page for Precise]

We can see that Desktop 64-bit and 32-bit are about 733 MB and 731 MB respectively and Server 64-bit and 32-bit are 679 MB and 661 MB respectively. (Here 1 MB = 1024 KB, so if your ISP calculates data as 1 MB = 1000 KB, do the maths as necessary).

---

**Tip:** If you want to save as much data as you can while downloading and already have an image of Ubuntu previously downloaded, you might want to [use `zsync` to update the iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54241/how-do-i-update-an-iso-with-zsync).

Answer (score 0):

All of the Ubuntu desktop downloads are under a gigabyte. If you want to know the megabytes that each edition of a desktop installation of Ubuntu is, here you go:

- **Ubuntu 13.10** - 895 MB
- **Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit** - 883 MB
- **Ubuntu 12.04** - 731 MB
- **Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit** - 733 MB