# How Much Size Required to Write Xubuntu ISO into USB?

Tags: boot, usb, xubuntu, disk-usage

I have a 4 GB USB stick and I am going to write the Xubuntu iso file into it. Will 4 GB be enough?

Comment: The size required is the same as the ISO file.

Comment: You haven't said which release; I've had Xubuntu ISOs that won't fit on a 2GB thumb-drive in recent cycles, but older releases will.  All will fit on a 4GB thumb-drive in my experience (ISO or *live* media itself; not installed system)

Comment: I use a 4GB USB for testing Ubuntu 21.04 and earlier Live and Persistent desktop versions. Persistence fills up quickly and then the drive will not boot. A Live install with no persistence was 0.7GB for Ubuntu 12.04, now it is 2.8GB for 20.04. A 4GB drive will still work great for a Live only drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the file size of an \*buntu iso image?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430040/what-is-the-file-size-of-an-buntu-iso-image)

Comment: @karel that is a pitiful comment, there was only one answer for Xubuntu in your link. it was for Xubuntu 12.04, which was 712MB. Xubuntu 20.04 is now 1.6 GB.

Comment: That's not the answer I referred to. It was [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/430046/). It makes sense to organize the questions into groups to avoid unnecessary duplication.

Comment: And how is the OP suppose to guess that? Your link opened on the question not that answer. And how is the OP suppose to know the download size is also the install size? Windows expands when installed. A full install of Ubuntu to USB takes over 8GB.

Answer (score 2):

XFCE 20.04 Iso has 1.74 GB, so your stick is large enough.

Since the answer to this question is so obvious, I'd like to mention, that I am referring to an USB-Stick that is used to install it on a hardware.

If you want to install Xubuntu **on an USB stick** (not recommended but possible), then you should have at least 8GB.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will work. I wrote this image on a 2GByte SD-Card.

You can write the Image on a USB-Stick to create a installation-USB-stick, so that you can install XUbuntu on your PC or Laptop with this stick.

You should use the Belena-Etcher for this, it is very easy you only have to select the right Flash-Drive.
https://www.balena.io/etcher/